# html input type radio checked doesn't work with ng-model

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I want my radio-input in the html preselected. It works fine when i just write:

```
<input type="radio" name="trackingOption" id="trackingOption" value="1"> Yes
<input type="radio" name="trackingOption" id="trackingOption" value="0" checked=""> No
```

But as soon as I add my ng-model for interact with my javaScript, the checked Option is gone

```
<input type="radio" name="trackingOption" ng-model="tracking" id="trackingOption" value="0" checked=""> No
```

Anyone know why "checked" doesn't work anymore with ng-model?!

Comment: I think you are looking for ng-checked.  Take a look at the angular docs.  https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChecked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to insert a ng-init expression which says which ng-model has the ng-value

```
<div ng-init="tracking=0">
     <input type="radio" name="trackingOption" ng-model="tracking" ng-value="1" id="trackingOption" value="1"> Yes
     <input type="radio" name="trackingOption" ng-model="tracking" ng-value="0" id="trackingOption" value="0" checked=""> No
</div>
```

Comment: this happens because tracking is undefined at first, you can also initialize that property on the directive scope :)

Answer (score 0):

you assign the value=0 that's why checked gone,so dont assign like that

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to interact with your model:

```
<input type="radio" name="trackingOption" ng-model="tracking" id="trackingOption" value="0"> No

<input type="radio" name="trackingOption" ng-model="tracking" id="trackingOption2" value="1"> Yes

The value is: {{tracking}}
```

See that the value of tracking gets updated each time you click on the other input. 
Then you need this part in your directive:

```
scope.$watch('tracking', (newValue, oldValue) => { //doyourstuffhere } )
```

Is this what you want?